# C++ Calculating wage earned and overtime using a structure.

Tags: c++, structure

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my code. I must use a structure to prompt the user for a workers idNumber, hoursWorked, and hourlyWage. I have the idNumber, hoursWorked, and hourlyWage working well, however the problem lies in my calc function. I cannot figure out how to calculate the money earned with overtime being 1.5 times and to be able to print that to the screen. I keep getting a mash up of weird numbers.

```
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;

struct Worker

{

    int idNumber;
    int hoursWorked;
    double hourlyRate;
    double earned;

};

void input(Worker & theData);
//Postcondition: theData.idNumber, theData.hoursWorked, and theData.hourlyRate are given input values
// the user must input into these values.
void print(const Worker &);

void calc(Worker & theWage);




void main()
{
    Worker Data;
    input(Data);

    print(Data);

    system("pause");

}

void input(Worker & theData)
{
    cout << "Enter the Employee idNumber";
    cin >> theData.idNumber;
    cout << "Enter the Hours Worked.";
    cin >> theData.hoursWorked;
    cout << "Enter the HoutlyRate for under 41 hours.";
    cin >> theData.hourlyRate;
}

void print(const Worker & w)
{
    cout << w.idNumber << "\n"
        << w.hoursWorked << "\n"
        << w.hourlyRate << "\n"
        << w.earned << endl;
}

void calc(Worker & theWage)
{
    if (theWage.hoursWorked <= 40)
    {
        theWage.earned = theWage.hoursWorked * theWage.hourlyRate;
    }
    else
    {
        int basePay;
        basePay = theWage.hoursWorked * theWage.hourlyRate;
        theWage.earned = (theWage.hoursWorked - 40) * 1.5 + basePay;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `calc()` function must be called in `main` before your `print()` function.

```
void main()
{
Worker Data;
input(Data);
calc(Data);  // This line was forgotten.
print(Data);
system("pause");
}
```

The weird number you saw was the uninitialized `earned` variable.

Comment: Haha. Not sure why I did not see that. Thank you for the fast response. Saved me some sanity.